# How to put button widget on label widget and decide its position in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How can I put the button widget on top of the background image?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()

# load image
logo = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\project\\front page.gif")
w = logo.width()
h = logo.height()

root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (w,h))

def helloCallBack():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Hello Python", "Hello World")

#create widgets
B = Button(root,text = "ASSOCIATIONS", command = helloCallBack,width = 20,padx = 20)
B.pack()

B1 = Button(root,text = "HELP", command = helloCallBack,width = 20,padx = 20)
B1.place(relx=1, x=-50, y=2, anchor=NE)
B1.pack()

w1 = Label(root, compound = CENTER, image = logo).pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is to put a background image in a widget using `place`, then put other widgets in that widget the way you normally do with either `pack` or `grid`

```
background=Label(root, image=logo).place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1, relheight=1)
b = Button(root, ...).pack(...)
```

Make sure you create the background first so that it has a lower stacking order.

If you really want to put a button in a label, just make the label the parent of the button and use `pack` or `grid` the way you normally do -- it's perfectly legal to pack something inside a Button or Label or any other widget (though, the end result might not be what you expect).

Comment: The other easy thing is put the button and image inside a canvas. Widgets inside a canvas always sit on top of everything else in the canvas. (It'd be nice if there was an option to layer things properly, but there isn't at the moment.)